# DbUpdate Exception when I try to delete entry from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

So, the issue is, I try to delete entry named **Post** in my **DeletePost Action** by simply searching for it and removing it from the **Database**.

```
public ActionResult DeletePost(int Id)
    {
        var postToDelete = ApplicationDbContext.Posts.Find(Id);
        postToDelete.Author = null;            
        ApplicationDbContext.Posts.Remove(postToDelete);
        ApplicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And the inner exception says:

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.Posts_Post_Id". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-Destiny-20170709034743", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Post_Id'.

I am not experienced enough with such issues, but here is my FluentAPI code for cascade delete, that I wrote much earlier.

```
modelBuilder
.Entity<Post>()
.HasRequired(x => x.Author)
.WithMany(x => x.Posts)
.HasForeignKey(x => x.AuthorId)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

And as I guess i will have to do the same thing for **PostId** but I have no idea how to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is nullable, I've checked in db preview right now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your database schema is wrong. The error returned by database suggests that you are trying to remove the post but this post is referenced by foreign key from AspNetUsers table ( column Post_id ). Are you sure you wanted to have Post_Id column in AspNetUsers table ? It doesn't seem to make sense. It should be designed the other way arround - The table which stores all the posts should reference user by foreign key, i.e.

> column User_Id which references primary key column in AspNetUsers table

Comment: I'm trying to remove post, not the User. So, by what you've said I should remove the List<Post> Posts property in ApplicationUser.cs and refer them to the user only?

Comment: I edited the answer while you was typing the comment

Comment: I'm not sure, I have no idea how to do this, as it may break my code at any moment. Can't I just enable cascade delete for PostId somehow?

Comment: In detail- I guess PostId column has been created when I've bound Post to their Author by setting the property **public ApplicationUser Author**, so when I delete this property, my code will absolutely break.

Comment: Setting this property should properly create column Author in Posts database. It should not create column Post_Id in AspNetUsers table.

Comment: That looks ok. Show AspNetUsers table now please

Comment: @HostileException The exception message indicates a column in **AspNetUsers** table. so show the picture of *that* table

Comment: Well, I guess you see the `Post_Id` column there (at the rightmost position)? You seem to have reference navigation property `public Post Post { get; set; }` in your `AspNetUser` class?

Comment: Yeah, I see it.

Comment: I just wanted to show that table does not generate columns such as "Author" or "Post" but goes by their id.

Comment: Column name is not a problem. As i said the problem is that your Users table reference table Posts by column post_id which is wrong. Can you show us the code creating AspNetUsers table ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after some research i realized that I have to delete any possbile reference before I delete object. So this is my solution for this issue.

```
public ActionResult DeletePost(int Id)
    {
        var allUsers = ApplicationDbContext.Users.ToList();
        var postToDelete = ApplicationDbContext.Posts.Single(c => c.Id == Id);
        foreach(var item in allUsers)
        {
            if (postToDelete.Subscribers.Contains(item))
                postToDelete.Subscribers.Remove(item);
        }
        ApplicationDbContext.Posts.Remove(postToDelete);
        ApplicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: It's not a solutions, it's a nasty workarround. You should be able to achieve your goal without doing such things and without need to amend model. Once again - the problem is that your AspNetUser table is being created incorectly and you should find the cause and fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the notification when you asked about the code which created **Post_Id**. I've noticed that this line didnt exist past some migrations, and have been added in one of recent ones. Now that is strange. Have a look: http://imgur.com/a/8R9Xk

Comment: It's probably not the Post-Author Relationship, but Post-Subscribers relationship.

Comment: Well, this time instead of "Taping it" i've eliminated the issue. I had to remove all subscribers before deleting the post itself.